# interior, closure and border on the Sorgenfrey line

Tags: general-topology

[General Topology] Display, for each following case, int$(A)$, $\overline{A}$ and $\operatorname{Fr}(A)$ in the topology of the Sorgenfrey line.

Could you see if that's correct? And can you help me?
$\DeclareMathOperator{\int}{int}$

Answer (score 4):

The set $A=[0,1)$ is open in the Sorgenfrey topology, so $\operatorname{int}A=A$. $A$ is also closed, because its complement is open:

$$\Bbb R\setminus A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}[-n,-n+1)\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}[n,n+1)\,.$$

Because $A$ is open, its complement is closed, so

$$\operatorname{bdry}A=(\operatorname{cl}A)\cap\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb R\setminus A)=A\cap(\Bbb R\setminus A)=\varnothing\,.$$

Now consider $\Bbb Z$. Clearly $\Bbb Z$ does not contain any set of the form $[x,y)$ with $x<y$, so as you say, $\operatorname{int}\Bbb Z=\varnothing$. But $\operatorname{cl}\Bbb Z$ cannot be empty, because it contains $\Bbb Z$. In fact $\Bbb Z$ is closed in the Sorgenfrey topology, so $\operatorname{cl}\Bbb Z=\Bbb Z$. One way to see this is to prove that if $\tau_S$ is the Sorgenfrey topology, and $\tau_E$ is the usual topology, then $\tau_E\subseteq\tau_S$. This isn’t hard: if $a<b$, then $(a,b)=\bigcup_{a<x<b}[x,b)$, which is open in $\tau_S$. And since every set that is open in the usual topology is also open in the Sorgenfrey topology, it follows that every set that is closed in the usual topology is closed in the Sorgenfrey topology. $\Bbb Z$ is closed in the usual topology, so it is closed in the Sorgenfrey topology. Finally, it’s clear that for any $n\in\Bbb Z$, every basic open nbhd $[n,x)$ of $n$ intersects $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$, so $\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z)=\Bbb R$, and $\operatorname{bdry}\Bbb Z=\Bbb Z$.

We can consider $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ together. Clearly $\Bbb Q$ also does not contain any set of the form $[x,y)$ with $x<y$, so $\operatorname{int}\Bbb Q=\varnothing$. The same is true of $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$. Every basic open set $[x,y)$ contains a non-empty open interval $(x,y)$, which contains both rational and irrational numbers, so $[x,y)\cap\Bbb Q\ne\varnothing\ne[x,y)\cap(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)$. That is, both $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ are dense in $\Bbb R$ in the Sorgenfrey topology, so $\operatorname{cl}\Bbb Q=\Bbb R=\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)$. And **that** implies that $\operatorname{bdry}\Bbb Q=\operatorname{bdry}(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)=\Bbb R$.

Now let $A=(0,1)$. $A$ is open in the usual topology, so it is open in the Sorgenfrey topology as well, and $\operatorname{int}A=A$. $\Bbb R\setminus[0,1]$ is open in the usual topology, so it is also open in the Sorgenfrey topology; this means that no point of $\Bbb R\setminus[0,1]$ can be in the Sorgenfrey closure of $(0,1)$. We know that $A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$, so the only points that remain to be considered are $0$ and $1$. $[1,2)$ is a Sorgenfrey open nbhd of $1$ disjoint from $A$, so $1\notin\operatorname{cl}A$. However, you can easily verify that every Sorgenfrey open nbhd of $0$ intersects $A$, so $0\in\operatorname{cl}A$. Thus, $\operatorname{cl}A=[0,1)$. The only point of $[0,1)$ that is in the Sorgenfrey closure of $\Bbb R\setminus(0,1)$ is $0$, which is actually in $\Bbb R\setminus(0,1)$, so $\operatorname{bdry}A=\{0\}$.

Now that I’ve gone through the first five in some detail, see if you can do (f) yourself.

Comment: okay, thank you!!! It helped me a lot

Comment: @IsadoraSuhadolnick: You’re welcome!